How to set up manipulate package
I am trying to figure out to analyze sepated group of different boxplot from the same matrix and avoid facet_wrap2 (too many data in there)
I would like visualize each amino acid independently e.i C8 only, then C8_IS, etc.. or even by group of two amino such as C8+C8_IS and then scroll into Orn + ORN_IS
folling script:
ggboxplot(intensity_test3, x = "sample", y = "Intensity", color = "day", palette = "lancet",
add="jitter", shape = "sample") + facet_grid2(~analyte~conc+method, margins = "vs", scales = "free")+
 theme_bw(base_size = 18)  +
 theme(strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 90))  + scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = TRUE, accuracy = 1))



If this is too many grids, couldn't you continue to use facet_wrap2 and filter the data to include only what you want to visualize separately? Maybe I'm not following.

I have a dataset of 33 amino acid (plus 33 Internal Standard/Control); using Facet_wrap2 , is a bit of a mess because, the Figure contained too much information, in total 66 samples.  So I was thinking to use Manipulate, in order to scroll down one sample at the time .ie C8 only , C8_IS etc... But if you have another idea, please let me know. G

Not sure exactly how you want to do it. Do you separate figures for each sample? You could filter the data to include only c8 samples? ggboxplot(intensity_test3 %>% dplyr::filter(sample %in% c(C8)), x=.... This literally just filters the data you give ggplot. You would have to switch out the C8 for each amino acid... but is that what you want? You could probably use a for loop if you wanted to make that faster if you were interested.

I would like to separate each figure for each sample (in other term showed together C8 and C8_IS panel_. Although, I never used for loop. Also ideally insert a statistical (t-test) p-value across days for each lowqc and highqc.  Thanks for your kind help.   P.S where I could upload my .csv example?

If you wanted to provide an example, you could save a minimal example (maybe fewer data points, just to get the point across) and save it as an object, just like the other one (intensity_test3). Then in R, execute this code: dput(intensity_test3) or whatever you named the object, and paste the output onto your question.

Thanks for that: below a quick code:                                                                   ggboxplot(example , x= "sample", y = "Intensity",
color = "day", palette = "lancet", add="jitter", shape = "WEEK")

facet_grid2(Type~Compound~conc+method ,   margins = "vs", scales = "free")
+theme _bw(base_size = 18)
+theme(strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 90))
scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = TRUE, accuracy = 1))


here the link of my example: https://filebin.net/n6tji0lwefor5hxb                                              I've failed to put a t-test across days and also tried to order without any success : levels=c("Val","13C2-Val","SUAC","13C5-SUAC"), thanks for your help

You want a t-test? Is this a separate issue?

So I just made up some data to match your graph and code. Here it is:
Just run this code to get the dataset I used.
intensity_test3 <- structure(list(sample = c("Low_qc", "Low_qc", "Low_qc", "Low_qc", 
"Low_qc", "Low_qc", "Low_qc", "Low_qc", "Low_qc", "Low_qc", "Low_qc", 
"Low_qc", "Low_qc", "Low_qc", "Low_qc", "Low_qc", "Low_qc", "Low_qc", 
"Low_qc", "Low_qc", "Low_qc", "Low_qc", "Low_qc", "Low_qc", "Low_qc", 
"Low_qc", "Low_qc", "Low_qc", "Low_qc", "Low_qc", "Low_qc", "Low_qc", 
"high_qc", "high_qc", "high_qc", "high_qc", "high_qc", "high_qc", 
"high_qc", "high_qc", "high_qc", "high_qc", "high_qc", "high_qc", 
"high_qc", "high_qc", "high_qc", "high_qc", "high_qc", "high_qc", 
"high_qc", "high_qc", "high_qc", "high_qc", "high_qc", "high_qc", 
"high_qc", "high_qc", "high_qc", "high_qc", "high_qc", "high_qc", 
"high_qc", "high_qc"), Intensity = c(1e+05, 1e+05, 1e+05, 1e+05, 
1e+05, 1e+05, 1e+05, 1e+05, 1e+05, 1e+05, 1e+05, 1e+05, 1e+05, 
1e+05, 1e+05, 1e+05, 1e+05, 1e+05, 1e+05, 1e+05, 1e+05, 1e+05, 
1e+05, 1e+05, 1e+05, 1e+05, 1e+05, 1e+05, 1e+05, 1e+05, 1e+05, 
1e+05, 2e+05, 2e+05, 2e+05, 2e+05, 2e+05, 2e+05, 2e+05, 2e+05, 
2e+05, 2e+05, 2e+05, 2e+05, 2e+05, 2e+05, 2e+05, 2e+05, 2e+05, 
2e+05, 2e+05, 2e+05, 2e+05, 2e+05, 2e+05, 2e+05, 2e+05, 2e+05, 
2e+05, 2e+05, 2e+05, 2e+05, 2e+05, 2e+05), day = c("day_1", "day_1", 
"day_1", "day_1", "day_2", "day_2", "day_2", "day_2", "day_3", 
"day_3", "day_3", "day_3", "day_4", "day_4", "day_4", "day_4", 
"day_1", "day_1", "day_1", "day_1", "day_2", "day_2", "day_2", 
"day_2", "day_3", "day_3", "day_3", "day_3", "day_4", "day_4", 
"day_4", "day_4", "day_1", "day_1", "day_1", "day_1", "day_2", 
"day_2", "day_2", "day_2", "day_3", "day_3", "day_3", "day_3", 
"day_4", "day_4", "day_4", "day_4", "day_1", "day_1", "day_1", 
"day_1", "day_2", "day_2", "day_2", "day_2", "day_3", "day_3", 
"day_3", "day_3", "day_4", "day_4", "day_4", "day_4"), analyte = c("C8", 
"C8_I6", "orn", "orn_IS", "C8", "C8_I6", "orn", "orn_IS", "C8", 
"C8_I6", "om", "orn_IS", "C8", "C8_I6", "orn", "orn_IS", "C8", 
"C8_I6", "orn", "orn_IS", "C8", "C8_I6", "orn", "orn_IS", "C8", 
"C8_I6", "om", "orn_IS", "C8", "C8_I6", "orn", "orn_IS", "C8", 
"C8_I6", "orn", "orn_IS", "C8", "C8_I6", "orn", "orn_IS", "C8", 
"C8_I6", "om", "orn_IS", "C8", "C8_I6", "orn", "orn_IS", "C8", 
"C8_I6", "orn", "orn_IS", "C8", "C8_I6", "orn", "orn_IS", "C8", 
"C8_I6", "om", "orn_IS", "C8", "C8_I6", "orn", "orn_IS"), conc = c(2.7, 
2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 
2.7, 2.7, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 
8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 
2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 
8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1, 8.1), method = c("new", 
"new", "new", "new", "new", "new", "new", "new", "new", "new", 
"new", "new", "new", "new", "new", "new", "old", "old", "old", 
"old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", 
"old", "old", "old", "old", "new", "new", "new", "new", "new", 
"new", "new", "new", "new", "new", "new", "new", "new", "new", 
"new", "new", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", 
"old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old", "old"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -64L))

Then I made a for loop and filter to only run each analyte. It should print each figure separately. You'' have to use the arrows in your plot viewer to see them as they are generated (assuming you're using R studio). Let me know if you have any questions, or if that's what you were looking for.
for (i in unique(intensity_test3$analyte)){
  p <- ggboxplot(intensity_test3 %>% dplyr::filter(analyte %in% c(i)), x = "sample", y = "Intensity", color = "day", palette = "lancet",
            add="jitter", shape = "sample") + facet_grid2(~analyte~conc+method, margins = "vs", scales = "free")+
    theme_bw(base_size = 18)  +
    theme(strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 90))  + scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = TRUE, accuracy = 1))
  print(p)
}

Here is an example of one figure it made.

EDIT:
You can certainly choose which panels go together. You could just do it like this (simply filter the data you give ggboxplot):
p1 <- ggboxplot(intensity_test3 %>% dplyr::filter(analyte %in% c("C8", "C8_I6")), x = "sample", y = "Intensity", color = "day", palette = "lancet",
                add="jitter", shape = "sample") + facet_grid2(~analyte~conc+method, margins = "vs", scales = "free")+
  theme_bw(base_size = 18)  +
  theme(strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 90))  + scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = TRUE, accuracy = 1))

p2 <- ggboxplot(intensity_test3 %>% dplyr::filter(analyte %in% c("orn", "orn_IS")), x = "sample", y = "Intensity", color = "day", palette = "lancet",
                add="jitter", shape = "sample") + facet_grid2(~analyte~conc+method, margins = "vs", scales = "free")+
  theme_bw(base_size = 18)  +
  theme(strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 90))  + scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = TRUE, accuracy = 1))

print(p1)
print(p2)

As for the t-test, this might be better for a separate question on SO or even perhaps the "stats" version of SO, Cross Validated if needed. It sounds like you have multiple factors and I don't know exactly what questions you would want to answer. Making a new post, and taking the time to fully describe what statistics you would like to perform would be most helpful for you.
