stat_compare_means() for multiple factors in faceted ggplot data
I am trying to add a p-value (t-test pairwise) across subgroups of data. See the example figure.

The following figure is group into groups and subgroups.
code:
SUAC_cv <- function(x, na.rm = FALSE)  (sd(x, na.rm = na.rm)/mean(x, na.rm = na.rm))*100
SUAC_a_cv <- aggregate(Intensity ~  Compound + conc + method+ sample+SET, SUAC, SUAC_cv)

SUAC_a_median <- aggregate (Intensity ~  Compound + conc + method + sample + SET, SUAC, FUN = "median")
SUAC_a_mean <- aggregate (Intensity ~  Compound + conc + method + sample + SET, SUAC, FUN = "mean")

for (i in unique(SUAC$subgroup)){ 
         p <- ggboxplot(SUAC %>% dplyr::filter(subgroup %in% c(i)), x = "sample", y = "Intensity", color = "SET", palette = "lancet",add = "jitter",
                                           shape = "WEEK")  +
             facet_grid2(~Compound~conc+method, margins = "vs", scales = "free")+
                 theme_bw(base_size = 18)  +
                 theme(strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 90))  + scale_y_continuous( minor_breaks=NULL, labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = TRUE, accuracy = 1)) 
         print(p)  
       }

I am not 100% familiarised with this website. Also, I am not an R expert neither.
Due to the limitation of characters, I can’t copy and paste the matrix, but I’ve attached the following file .csv:
link: https://filebin.net/n6tji0lwefor5hxb
Basically, I would like cluster the data by a boxplot visualization.
I am mainly comparing two different samples LOW and HIGH_QC over time.
Although the trick is  how to work once you have so many multi-sub-categories.
Here my example:
Samples LOW and HIGH_QC are part of 2 different analytes, in this case SUAC and SUAC-13C5.
Also, each LOW and HIGH_QC are subgroup from another major group labelled as NEW and OLD.
As well as, NEW and OLD are subgroups of another major annotation 2.7 and 8.1.
Each LOW and HIGH_QC corresponded data for different days (x3days) = 3 boxplot in this case.
Hence, I am trying to analyse the statistical significance over time using t-test.
Unfortunately, I can’t figure out how performed a proper code, for STAT analysis, due to a multiple groups “on top of each other”.
Gio

What exactly is your question? Could you edit your question to clarify what you are asking, as well as include data to make this question reproducible? Good luck!

example data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79039811/how-to-set-up-manipulate-package?noredirect=1#comment139392797_79039811

Please edit your question to include the data (dont post a link in the comments) as well as clarify what you are asking

Thanks @jpsmith , I added my comment on the figure. I hope it is more clear now

Are each of the days independent? Further, is day_1 and day_2 samples the same material? Do you want to test for differences among qc's? or days? A t-test should be between two groups.

You have multiple factors here (multiple independent variables) and I want to make sure you actually want a t-test. Maybe you want some sort of ANOVA. One you figure that out, there is a couple ways you could approach this. Rather, use built-in stats functions in ggboxplot (if they exist) or use a function that will perform the statistics for you, extract them, and create labels.

Hi @scott.pilgrim.vs.r, first   each day represent a repeated-measures  of each QC,          . Second day_1 and day_2 samples are the same QC material.  My test should based on find out if over days QCs values changed, and how statistical is the changed (So analyze how the differences between the same group of data are changed over time). In theory over time both QC samples should have similar values ,  hence, you shouldn't observed a huge statistical difference.

You may want a repeated measures ANOVA. Here is a link that might help you. https://www.datanovia.com/en/lessons/repeated-measures-anova-in-r/
Let me know if this helps, and I can help you more Monday.

Hi @scott.pilgrim.vs.r, thanks for the link; One-way repeated measures ANOVA is the way to go, aim to investigate if over time multiple measument of QCs changed and if  YES how much is the chagend (sign or not). Intensity QCs and Time (days) are the two main Facotrs.   Thanks again!
